# Angular multi step form routing

Tags: javascript, angular

I am fairly new to angular and I'm building a multi step form using angular 4. Currently the component structure is as follows:

```
-apply.component
--step-one.component
--step-two.component
--step-three.component
```

Router is set up like this:

```
{
 path: '',
 redirectTo: '/apply',
 pathMatch: 'full'
},
{
 path: 'apply',
 component: ApplyComponent,
 children: [
   {
     path: 'personalInfo',
     component: StepOneComponent,
     outlet: 'step1'
   },
   {
      path: 'employmentInfo',
      component: StepTwoComponent,
      outlet: 'step2'
   }
```

Router outlets in ApplyComponent:

```
 <router-outlet name="step1">Child 1 in apply comp</router-outlet>
 <router-outlet name="step2">Child 2 in apply comp</router-outlet>
```

As the use completes one section, it should hide as the next sections shows. Each section is a router outlet on the parent component.

I am trying to figure out the best way to orchestrate the show/hide of each section. I have figured out how to activate each route from the previous route but how should I hide or destroy the previous route (section)? Should each section actually be generated in a ? How can I orchestrate interactions (go back/edit/next) for all of the different sections?

Edit: Another idea, should all the components be defined in the parent and then just show/hide as the move to next step and then update route? I might be thinking of this backwards in my current implementation of router updates components instead of components update route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using a single router-outlet to display the steps.  Remove the named router outlet from your routes configuration and remove the name from the router outlet mark up.  I assume you already have next and previous buttons to move between the steps.  Now you don't have to worry about show/hide logic, the router takes care of that for you.  You may need to add [Route Guards](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#guards) to prevent the user from tampering with the url.

Your router config would look like this:

```
{
 path: 'apply',
 component: ApplyComponent,
 children: [
   {
     path: 'personalInfo',
     component: StepOneComponent
   },
   {
      path: 'employmentInfo',
      component: StepTwoComponent,
   }
}
```

Your single router outlet would look like this:

```
<router-outlet>Steps will be loaded here</router-outlet>
```

Comment: Yeah, I started playing with that earlier and it is probably the direction i'll take. Thanks!